# Changing a parameter in wheel colliders in code

Tags: unity-game-engine

`wheelColliderLeftFront.GetComponent<WheelCollider>().sidewaysFriction.stiffness = 2;`
Im trying to change this value via code but its not working

`public WheelCollider wheelColliderLeftFront;`

I referenced it here

I'm getting an error saying cannot modify return value of `wheelcollider.sidewaysfriction` because its not a variable

Answer (score 0):

as described in the wheel collider documentation of unity, stiffness is not a value but a curve. So you are doing the same thing as trying to write an image into an integer.

[Wheel collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-WheelCollider.html)

[Wheel friction curve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelFrictionCurve.html)

[wheel friction curve stiffness](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WheelFrictionCurve-stiffness.html)

as you can see in the last link you have to adress the stiffness curve and not set a value.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I think you are on the right track just need a tweak in syntax. This one assumes wheelColliderLeftFront is a WheelCollider in script.

```
WheelFrictionCurve wfc = wheelColliderLeftFront.sidewaysFriction;
wfc.stiffness += 1;
wheelColliderLeftFront.sidewaysFriction = wfc;
```

if its a game object with a wheel collider in script just do

```
WheelFrictionCurve wfc = wheelColliderLeftFront.GetComponent<WheelCollider>().sidewaysFriction;
wfc.stiffness += 1;
wheelColliderLeftFront.GetComponent<WheelCollider>().sidewaysFriction = wfc;
```